# Check with day is it by date (Sunday,Monday)

Tags: java

i am trying to make a program that you insert day , month , year ... and its said witch day is it (sunday,monday.....) i make that but that sometimes working and sometimes not.. try you for the help !!

(i need to do it only on java not use date system functions or someting like that)

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  

System.out.println("Enter Today Day : ");
int day = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Today Month : ");
int dayMonth = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Today Year : ");
int year = scan.nextInt();

String[] days = {"Friday","Saturday", "Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday" };
int howManyDays = (year-1916)*365 + dayMonth + day ;  
int whatDay = howManyDays%7;
System.out.println(days[whatDay]);
```

Comment: Your arithmetic is the culprit. There aren't always 365 days in a year. (Also not quite sure what `(year-1916)` is there for)

Comment: I really would advise using Java's built in Date/Calendar functions as apposed to making your own. Data/Time is a very complicated subjects (time zones, calendar shifts, leap year/seconds). And trying replicate it's function will end in tears.

Comment: I guess you're not considering that some years have 366 days...

Comment: And just adding the month number and day together really isn't a good basis for anything... if you really want to write this yourself for an assignment, you'll need a lot more logic than this. Hint: the number of days in each month matters, as do leap years.

Comment: "*i need to do it only on java not use date system functions or someting like that*" is it homework assignment or you like tormenting yourself? One of nice things about programming is ability to reuse existing solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about the algorithm for finding the weekday of a certain date, and is really not specific to Java.

See Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Calculation